# rendering list-images bbui from database mysql

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a list bbui image using ajax call in a mysql database, but in the process I do not get the same format as the image of bbui list, following my code

```
var idmember='glut1';
    function dataOnLoad_initialLoad(element) {
        var listItem, dataList = element.getElementById('dataList');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/history.php?id_member=" + idmember,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(xhr, settings, exception) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    listItem = document.createElement('div');
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
                    listItem.onclick = function() {
                        bb.pushScreen('detail.htm', 'detail');
                    };
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', val.tglorder);
                    listItem.innerHTML = val.namastatus;
                    dataList.appendChild(listItem);

                    var order = val.idorder;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

and then the code implemented in beforedetail.html like this code

```
<div id="dataList" data-bb-type="image-list" data-bb-images="none" data-bb-style="arrowlist">
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but my case was to generate an image list with a header to group items.

I did it the only way i know ho and it worked but am open to suggestions on how to do it better.

Here is the js code:

```
var listItem, header,
    dataList = document.getElementById('dataList');// this is my list already in the DOM

var list = [];
var user = localDB.getScreenName();
$.ajax({
    url: reg.api(),
    data: {action: 'getAttire', formData: user},
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'result',
    beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById('indicator').style.display = 'block';
    },
    complete: function() {
        document.getElementById('indicator').style.display = 'none';
    },
    success: function(res) {
        //showbList();
        var title = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(res[i].item, title) === -1) {
                title.push(res[i].item);//creates header array with unique values cos i had headers with duplicate names
            }
            //  This creates header Array from the list
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < title.length; k++) {
            header = document.createElement('div');
            header.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'header');
            header.id = 'headers';
            header.innerHTML = title[k];
            header.style.background = '#f6f6f6';
            header.style.fontSize = '20px';
            header.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            // header.style.boxShadow = ''
            list.push(header);//header created here
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                if (header.innerHTML === 'Bag' && res[i].item === 'Bag') {
                    //var date = 
                    listItem = document.createElement('div');
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-img', res[i].img_link);
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', res[i].name);
                    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-accent-text', 'Added: '+jQuery.timeago(res[i].date));
                    listItem.setAttribute('dressup',res[i].DRESS_ID);
                    listItem.setAttribute('id','wardropeLink');
                    listItem.innerHTML = "Suited for: " + res[i].suited;
                    listItem.style.color = "#fff";
                    listItem.onclick =  function() {
                    var selected = document.getElementById('wardropeLink').getTitle();
                    console.log(selected); // trying to get d title of a selected or clicked list but it returns the whole group. still working on it
                };
                list.push(listItem); //list item for a particular header created here
            }
            if (header.innerHTML === 'Trousers' && res[i].item === 'Trousers') {
                listItem = document.createElement('div');
                listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
                listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-img', res[i].img_link);
                listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', res[i].name);
                listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-accent-text', jQuery.timeago(res[i].date));
                listItem.innerHTML = "Suited for: " + res[i].suited;
                listItem.style.color = "#fff";
                listItem.onclick = function() {
                    handleWardrope.listItems(res[i].DRESS_ID);
                };
                list.push(listItem);
            }

        }
    }

    var items = dataList.getItems();
    if (items.length > 0) {
        //list.insertItemBefore(item, items[0]);
    } else {
        dataList.refresh(list);//list added to DOM
        if (bb.scroller) {
            bb.scroller.refresh();
        }
    }


}
});
return false;
```

Hope this helps.

Warning and still trying to get the onclick function work for a particular list item but it seems to group them cos of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

concerning the problem i had about getting the title of a list item
i solved it by calling the list selected function and then acted on the getTitle of the selected item.
code

```
listItem.onclick = function(){
var selected = document.getElementById('dataList').selected;
 console.log(selected.getAttribute('dressup'));
}
```

what i did wrong before was i tried to get d selected item on d item itself and not on the imagelist.